# onComplete doesnt work in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have this code and when video finish it does not alert but i can only play video again. I found a lot of examples where code is like my.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js"></script>

<div id="container">This'll be the player</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jwplayer("container").setup({
          file:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-FbXkGqoek",
          flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
          height:400,
          width:600,
          events:{
              onComplete: function() {
               alert("Done");
              }
          },
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

See the example : http://jsfiddle.net/ksK2A/

I only see a small error is the extra comma after `events: {}` the extra comma may cause problem in IE or older browser.

Comment: Now, i try it on my server and it is working. I really understand, why it doesnt work on my localhost. Many thanks

Comment: You need to at least run in a local web server environment in order for events to fire using the JS API.